# Removing link reference in browser

Tags: html, css

I am using the following code to toggle my mobile navigation

html

```
<a href="#" class="toggle-nav"><p>toggle</p></a>
```

I have a function which attaches the proper code/css and just need it to act as a button but not go anywhere (hence the '#').

However I want nothing to show up when it clicks/hover, since the browser usually indicates where the link is going, I don't want that (or anything else) to show

Comment: Why don't you use a `button` instead?

Comment: What you're asking for is outright impossible; the browser will **always** show a hyperlink. You could use JavaScript's `e.preventDefault()` if you really don't want the hyperlink to actually do anything.

Comment: `href="javascript:void()"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Michael suggested, why not try using a `button` instead? Your code would look like this

```
<button class="toggle-nav"><p>toggle</p></button>
```

All you'd have to do is change any CSS/JS you have to reference the button instead of an a tag.

Comment: This way I have to style/restyle the default button class

Comment: But it looks like that's what I'll have to do

Answer (score 0):

You may style the link with `pointer-events`.

```css
.toggle-nav {
  pointer-events: none
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="toggle-nav"><p>toggle</p></a>
```